# Why minimising the MSE in Variance-Bias tradeoff?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics, variance

As I understand the Variance-Bias tradeoff, modifying estimators to minimise bias might increase the variance of the estimator and vice-versa. For the simple case of the biased variance estimator, using $\frac{n}{(n-1)}$ as a correction factor might overcome the bias but the estimator has an un-optimal variance.

At several places regarding this, as a more suited goal of supervised learning, correction factors to minimise the Mean Squared Error are used ($\frac{n}{n+1}$ for the sample variance). ***Why is minimising MSE a better objective (than that of minimising only bias)?***

Comment: Better than what? $\qquad$

Comment: Better than the objective of minimising the bias only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unbiasedness by itself doesn't amount to much.  Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n \sim \text{i.i.d. Bernoulli} (p)$, i.e.

$$X_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability } p, \\ 0 & \text{with probability } 1-p. \end{cases}$$

Then $X_1$ is an unbiased estimator of $p$, but it's a lousy estimator.  On the other hand $(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$ is a far better unbiased estimator, since it is highly probable that it is close to $p$ because its variance is small.

In some settings, every unbiased estimator is far worse than many biased estimators.  Here is my own example of that: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206006.pdf

For the record, let us recall an identity: $$ \text{mean squared error} = \text{variance} + (\text{bias})^2. $$

Comment: I understood why consideration of variance and bias both is necessary as a criterion for a good estimator. But how does MSE represent a good estimator? Is there any reason to use the $\text{variance}+(\text{bias})^2$ to account for both these, over any possible combination of these two quantities?

Comment: MSE is zero when the estimator is perfect, and gets bigger as it moves away from perfection.  Hence minimizing it would appear to make sense. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to be overly insistent, but are there other functions minimising which also might make sense? To quote you, `the smallness of the mean squared error as a criterion for
evaluating estimators is not necessarily sacred anyway.
`

Comment: Would not several combinations, say Variance + bias also follow "being zero for a perfect estimator, and increasing with increasingly poor estimators"?

Comment: @SatwikPasani : Correct.  There is a reason why it intuitively makes sense.  But no theorem says it's the right thing to do. But MERELY making an estimator unbiased can result in a terrible estimator, as the example in my answer above shows. $\qquad$

Comment: One drawback of variance plus bias is that if you change to measuring quantities in centimeters from measuring them in meters, then the estimator that minimizes that sum changes.  That doesn't happen with the variance plus the square of the bias, because the variance is measured in the same units in which the square of the bias is measured. $\qquad$

Comment: This last point, I reckon, should be emphasized: even in mathematics, "units" are important. If a formula is not homogeneous, then something is often fishy.