# MLE of variance minimising the mean squared error

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics, variance, maximum-likelihood

While [reading](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumLikelihood.html) up on the derivation of a Maximum Likelihood Estimator for population variance, the MLE for Variance ends up being the biased sample variance, $\frac{n-1}{n}S^2$ where $S^2$ is the unbiased sample mean. As satisfactorily discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862748/why-minimising-the-mse-in-variance-bias-tradeoff/), minimising the MSE can be a good criterion for selecting an estimator, as it accounts for both the variance and the bias of the estimator.

Variance estimator minimising the MSE would be [$\frac{n-1}{n+1}S^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Variance), which is different from it's MLE. ***Which estimator should then be chosen?***

**Why is there this discrepancy, if the MLE is supposed to reflect the best attempt at estimating the unknown quantity possible with the given data?** (Is this something to do with substituting the sample mean for the population mean while deriving the variance MLE, a step I fail to understand well?)

Comment: "if the MLE is supposed to reflect the best attempt" . . . . That's a fairly big "if". In what senses the MLE is best, is a question whose answer is not at all straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is worth to specify that you are talking about normal distribution. Otherwise, $S^2$ is not (necessarily) the MLE of $\text{var}(X)$.

"if the MLE is supposed to reflect the best attempt..."

There is no universally best method to derive estimators. ML maximization is only one possible and widely accepted method. However, its justification mainly based on the asymptotic ($n\to \infty$) properties of the estimators rather than small sample features like vanishing bias. On a slightly theoretical ground, what would you expect from a ``good'' estimator?

1) Consistency, $ \hat{\tau}_n \xrightarrow{p} \tau$.

1.1) Asymptotically unbiased $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}\hat{\tau}_n=\tau$.

2)  Utilize all the sample available  information in the sense of Fisher Information, i.e., $\mathcal{I}_{\hat{\tau}_n}(\tau)=\mathcal{I}_{X_1,...,X_n}(\tau) $.

ML estimators satisfies these three conditions, furthermore, under some regular conditions (finite variance and independence of $\tau$ and the support of $X_1,...,X_n$ the MLE will converge in distribution to a normal r.v with the minimal possible variance (Cramer-Rao lower bound; $\mathcal{I}^{-1}_{X_!,...,X_n}(\tau)$).

So.. if it is so good why the aforementioned ''discrepancies'' occur?  As you can see, some of the desired properties may hold only for $n\to \infty$. As such, if for some reason you are dealing with small $n$ and value ubiasness - ML estimator won't necessarily be your best choice. Another possible reason to reject the method is intractability of the estimator. Deriving MLE for $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is mathematically easy, but  once your parametric space is of higher dimension or/and the ML function is not so smooth and ``nice'' - the task of maximization may become pretty troublesome.

Strictly speaking of the estimator of $\text{var}(X)$ in $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. All the presented estimators are asymptotically equivalent in the terms of bias and efficiency as $n\pm 1 \approx n$ for large enough $n$. Thus, for very large samples is doesn't matter which one you choose. For small samples, you may care about bias and efficiency (in terms of MSE), so it is reasonable to choose from one of the other modified estimators.

Comment: I understood the fact that MLE predictions are valid only for large $n$. Sorry to be a bit slow but is there any intuitive reason why the MLE does not minimise MSE? As in are these two calculations trying to find out different things about the estimator, in which case the different answer is justified, and so is the fact that selection depends on which quantities these two try to assess and which of those is valuable for the application.

Comment: Why the MLE have to minimize MSE for every possible $n$? MLE, intuitively, is the value that is most probable for the parameter of interest (in the frequentist perception) given the available data. In some cases it may coincide with other estimators and minimize the MSE as well - like in a linear regression where the MLE similar to the OLS estimators. And in other cases, e.g., $S^2$ in the normal distribution - it is not.